# how to combine two scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
// ===========for checking the size of an image
$(document).on('change', '#images', function() {
    files = this.files;
    size = files[0].size;

  //max size 50kb => 50*1000
    if (size < 1000141) {
        return true;

        //break;
        // end;
    }
    alert('File size greater than 1MB cannot be uploaded');
    return false;
});

//===========used for showing the preview of image
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#blah').show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$("#images").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});
```

The first script shows the alert but the second one give the preview if the size greater than 1MB.

Comment: so you want second function to work only if the filesize comes within the limits, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31692916/1479535

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on your mouse events

`onmouseover='firstscriptFuncname'`  < space >  `'second script func name'`

like this

`onmouseover='readURL(input) readURL(input)'`

Don't use a comma for separation, only a space is enough.

Comment: $(document).on('change', '#images', function()       in this if i want to use onmouseover='readURL(input) readURL(input)' instead of 'change'

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/5y43h13x/)

I think you can do something like this. There are other ways also which can help you accomplish this.

```
// ===========for checking the size of an image
$(document).on('change', '#images', function() {
    files = this.files;
    size = files[0].size;
    //max size 50kb => 50*1000
    if (size < 1000141) {
        readURL(this);
        return true;
    }
    alert('File size greater than 1MB cannot be uploaded');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: the name of the image is displayed after the alert

Comment: <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPropertyType" class="col-sm-12 control-label labelpropertypost">Upload Photos *:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    
    <br />
     <input type="file" class="" name="images" id="images" multiple>
    </div> 
    <div id="ph_err" style="margin-top: 10px; color: red;"></div> 
    <div class="col-sm-5 ">
  <div class="form-group">
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" width="100"  />
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>      this is my form for uploading image